# Git for personal backups?

Tags: git, backup

I am looking for a way (not a service, a (set of) tool(s)) to make personal backups (mostly photos & videos) using a solution existing in whatever OS. That's why git sounds interesting.

The thing is that I don't want to keep track of everything pushed in the repository, I would like to disable the versioning functionality so that when I delete a photo and sync the folder with my server, this photo is actually deleted and not saved in revision n - 1.

Is there any way to do this with git? Or maybe do someone know a good multi platform & open source solution for backups?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Of course, it would be for more than 2 Gb (right now 400Gb) of data. Meaning I don't want to pay for a cloud service. I can host it on my own server.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the point, but what's wrong with a good old file host or shared web hosting to FTP files to?

Comment: You ever heard of dropbox?  http://dropbox.com it's free, it's awesome, and its great, it's semi-versioned and you can access it from any computer or it integrates into your OS.

Comment: Or a solution "in the cloud" like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) which you can access from anywhere - Windows, Mac, Linux - even your iPhone, iPad, Blackberry or Android phone...

Comment: To be able to use environment integrated tools on Windows like gitortoise:)

Comment: @autsinbv I know dropbox, unfortunately the server is not open source and I have hundreds of Gb to save.

Comment: "I want a versioning tool without versioning" sounds weird. Also "I want everything for nothing" is a quite enthusiastic attitude :D

Comment: @autsinbv: you don't get it at all. By syncing my files on a server at home, on my laptop, on my school computer, or wherever, the chances to lose anything are ... 0! With an external HDD - and that's what I am doing right now - I can't sync remotely.

Comment: @autsinbv: that's why I am asking for tools/ideas, not a solution. I am hoping ubuntu one's server sources will be released one day to run it ourselves...

Comment: The OP never said he was looking for 400 GB of free remote hosting, he always mentioned backing up to his own server.

Comment: rsync is the best for now. But I wish ZFS (Solaris's great filesystem) was available at least for Linux! (If it was, it was the best fs for server-side storage)

Comment: @JulioGuerra: Did you consider that with such syncing services any unintentional file deletions/corrupted/etc. would get propagated to other devices? Perhaps this doesn't matter in your case, but I found this fact disturbing when I was considering sync-based backups without any kind of versioning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of git, you might want to look at [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for that kind of tasks.

Comment: The huge benefit of git would be versioned backups. rsync obviously doesn't do this for you. Versioned backups are important if one of your files (say... your encrypted bitcoin wallet) gets corrupted. Without a versioned backup of *some* kinda, you'd be effed

Comment: This is the difference OP wants, he does not want versioned backups and is looking for a solution for that, rsync might take care of that

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to remove a file completely from a git repo:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch deleted_image.jpg' HEAD
```

Too much hassle for a personal backup though.

You can use something like robocopy in the <strike>backup</strike> mirror mode.

> Mirror A to B, destroying any files in
>   B that are not present in A (/MIR),
>   copy files in restartable mode (/Z) in
>   case network connection is lost:

```
Robocopy C:\A \\backupserver\B /MIR /Z
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Or rsync can be used. Use --delete option while mirroring.

http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/unix/nix_rsync/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is a great service for doing what you describe. Basically, it keeps a folder synced with an online backup. It also allows you to sync files across multiple computers or view the files online.

Comment: Thats easy to use, but neither client-side nor server-side programs are free/open source.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sugarsync.com](http://Sugarsync.com) too. It's got 5gb of free storage; similar to dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to rsync, [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) works pretty well for bi-directional sync-ing

Answer (score 1):

I use 2gb free ZenOK [Online Backup](http://onlinebackup.zenok.com/) has is good tool to store my photos from work, it works and I don't have to worry about burning DVDs or buying an external hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

rsync has been mentioned, but if you want versioning too, then look at rsnapshot.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using rsnapshot in this case, if git would also provide versioning by default?

Comment: rsnapshot is very easy to setup, and in my case I was already using rsync for backups, so rsnapshot is just an extension of that, and so I didn't have to learn a whole new system.

Comment: I see, so rsync+rsnapshot would provide the option to have versioned and unversioned backups, while git would basically only do versioned

Comment: yes - so if you want to run a random adhoc backup run your usual rsync, otherwise rsnapshot can be run as and when needed, so you control when the versioning occurs.  Of course rsnapshot can be scheduled as well in cron etc.

Answer (score 0):

[git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com) looks relevant. It stores only
hashes of files in git repository, while actual files content are stored in
[different backends](https://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/). So it
allows managing files with git and still being able to "drop" some files from
backup completely (you have to drop it from all backends where it is stored.
Usually annex will try to preserve you from doing so, but all you need is
`--force` flag)